# How to add to HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android-studio, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have in my xml file, an empty HorizontalScrollView.
how do I add a picture to the HorizontalScrollView through the **Java file**.

Answer (score 0):

### plese refer this example

add scrollview inside dynamic view

https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/